# How to train SSD model in Tensorflow Mobile/Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a dataset of 300*300 images together with boxes and labels of objects in them. I want to use the SSD network to detect these objects on images. I also want to do it on mobile devices, so I need the final model to be compatible with TF Mobile/Lite. The question is: **where should I start from?**

I know that SSD is supported by TF Mobile/Lite (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15633 for example). And I believe that there should be not trained SSD model for TF, which I just need to train on my own dataset. But I could only find the pre-trained ones. I also couldn't find any tutorial, which explains how one should train the existing models on his own dataset.

So, to be more precise:

1. Is my assumption, that I should get the non-trained model and train it on my own dataset with some simple script, correct?
2. If **yes** then where can I get this model and a training script?
3. Do I need to train it using the desktop TF and then convert to Mobile/Lite models?

Comment: did you succeed in training such model? I'm trying to train ssd mobilenet first but it fails: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/issues/185

Answer (score 5):

1) Unless you have a massive amount of data, no, your assumption is wrong. Most applications today start from a model pretrained on Imagenet and then fine-tune it to whatever your dataset might be. The reason for this is that while the dataset is different, many features learned from Imagenet are useful for the new dataset too, so you can fine tune to it avoiding the need to have huge amounts of data (and a lot of time/computational power).

2) The [tensorflow models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) repository is the place to look at. Please note, the graph architecture and the weights are separate so if you do decide to start from scratch, just don't load the weights when you start the training.

3) Yes, tflite is a mobile-oriented optimized runtime, the graph is still trained ondesktops with the normal Tensorflow, frozen and then you can use the frozen graph's `.pb` file in your application built with tflite. For more details on how to do all of that, you should check Tensorflow's website, they have many guides covering each step (and going in detail over all of them here is just impossible).

Comment: Am I right that this link https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection gives me what I'm looking for? An SSD (or any other multibox detector) model, which I can easily train on my own dataset?

Comment: "easily"... Well.. it won't be a "run this and it will magically work" process, but that's a good place to start from, yes

Comment: Well, by saying easily I mean "get something, which solves the problem at least somewhat better then random". I've never worked with neural nets, but expect that high-level API, which Tensorflow claims to be, should let me achieve this goal.

Comment: Tensorflow is indeed a high-level API, but what you seek is higher still. Training neural networks is half science half art at the moment, you'll run into walls a lot and you'll need to experiment with different things. It's just how the field is, this is a live research after all :) If you're a complete beginner search for guides/tutorials on how to retrain SSD-Mobilenet for a new dataset (there is quite a few out there, quality varies and I don't think there isn't any on the official TF website). Start there, make it work, then replace the data with yours and try your luck

Comment: That's why I created this topic: I couldn't find any article about the SSD network training with TensorFlow. Only the detection API usage, that I posted above. Actually I don't even think that I need to use SSD architecture. Any multibox detector is fine.

Comment: retraining works ok with `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets` but fails with SSD mobile net (`ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync`) on both Windows and Ubuntu: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/issues/185

Comment: @Lingviston If you need any multibox (e.g. coco inception and not ssd mobilenet coco), then there is great article and source code (it can be done on Windows and on Ubuntu) https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10